# servlet mapping in web.xml (*.* vs *.any_pattern)

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I have the following URL pattern:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>name_of_a_servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.some_pattern</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

If i have more than one pattern in url pattern e.g: `*.htm`, `*.css`, `*.do` etc, can I use `*.*` in url pattern?  or I have to use like this;

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.*` is not a valid URL pattern. The `*` can only be at start **or** end of the pattern. If you intend to cover *every* HTTP request, then you need to use `/*`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>name_of_a_servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'd however question if that servlet couldn't better be a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

Answer (score 0):

The URL mapping syntax is defined in the Servlet API spec (I'm referencing 2.4) for this information:

> A string beginning with a '/' character and ending with a '/*' suffix
>   is used for path mapping. 
>   A string beginning with a '*.' prefix is used as an extension mapping.  A string containing only the '/' character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
>   All other strings are used for exact matches
>   only.

So the short answer is that a url-pattern is meant to be a single url pattern. You'd have to make multiple patterns to match the three patterns exclusively.

Comment: oh and the pattern spec is defined in section 11.2 in the servlet 2.4 spec

Comment: That isn't the OP's question. You can have multiple `<url-pattern>` entries in a single `<servlet-mapping>`. OP's concrete question is how to have only one. OP's attempt of using `*.*` apparently failed, that's why he asked it here.

Comment: also my wording was confusing wrt to mapping/pattern

Answer (score -1):

`<url-pattern>*.some_pattern</url-pattern>`
Should be
`<url-pattern>/*.some_pattern</url-pattern>` // slash before path

or
`-pattern>/path-pattern</url-pattern>`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [answer]